# How to understand that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-field containing all intervals?

Tags: measure-theory

Since I cannot understand the definition of Borel $\sigma$-field, which is defined as $$\mathcal B=\bigcap\{\mathcal F:\mathcal F \text{ is a }\sigma\text{ -field containing all intevals}\}.$$
We say that $\mathcal B(\mathbb{R} )$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field generated by all intervals and we call the elements of $\mathcal B$ Borel sets.
        $\mathbb R$ is a set containing all real numbers. $\mathcal F$ is the $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb R$, then $\mathcal F \text{ is a proper }\text{collection of subsets of }\mathbb R$ satisfying 3 conditions of the definition of the $\sigma$-field. But how can we say that $\mathcal F$ contains all the intervals? Some examples? 
Thank you!

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb R$ is an example of a $\sigma$-field containing all the intervals.

Comment: How about a ''smaller'' $\sigma$-field?

Comment: I’m not aware of any simple (i.e. easy to describe) smaller $\sigma$-fields other than the Borel (or Lebesgue) $\sigma$-field, unfortunately, but I imagine you won’t find those examples particularly helpful. It might help instead to think of a simple (say, finite) collection of sets $\cal C$, and to work out what $\sigma (\cal C)$ is for that example. Here, $\sigma (\cal C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field containing $\cal C$.

Comment: Consider $\mathcal F:= \{\mathbb R, \emptyset,(1,2), (-\infty,1] \cup [2,\infty) \}$, does the interval $(3,4) \text{ belong to } \mathcal F$? I am confused that (3,4) is not an element of $\mathcal F$ but it is an element of the element of the $\mathcal F.$

Comment: $(3,4)$ does not belong to $\cal F$, given your definition. Only the sets $\mathbb R$, $(1,2)$, and their complements are in $\cal F$. Have you worked out what $\sigma (\cal F)$ is?

Comment: To put another way, suppose $A = \{ a, b, c, d\}$, and suppose $x$ is not equal to any of $a$, $b$, $c$, or $d$. Then $x$ is not in $A$. This is the exact same question as what you asked. Just define $a$ = $\mathbb R$, $b = \emptyset$ and so on, with $x=(3,4)$.

Comment: What I really want to ask is how a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$ containing all intervals, since the example above shows that the (3,4) is not contained in $\mathcal F$ while $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: The $\mathcal F$ you've defined is a $\sigma$-field, but it is not a $\sigma$-field that contains all the open intervals. I'm not sure what you be when you say "how". You can just define a $\sigma$-field, call it $\mathcal G$, such that $\mathcal G$ contains all the open intervals. You don't know much about what $\mathcal G$ is, but you do know it contains the open intervals and is a $\sigma$-field (and thus must contain the Borel sets). Then you take the collection of all such $\mathcal G$ and take their intersection. This gives you the Borel sets.

Comment: The $\mathcal F$ you've defined is not such a $\mathcal G$, so it is not part of the intersection. The best I can say regarding "how" you do this is that you do so by definition. You can try to make the whole thing rigorous by formalising it in set theory, but typically we're not too bothered by those formal details.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of $\sigma$-fields that contain the (open, closed, half-open/closed) intervals. That is, if $\mathcal F \in \mathcal A$, then $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-field, and for every $a,b\in\mathbb R$, we have that $(a,b),[a,b],[a,b),(a,b] \in \mathcal F$. We then define the Borel $\sigma$-field to be $\mathcal B = \cap \mathcal A$. (Note: We could have taken $\mathcal A$ to just be a collection of $\sigma$-fields that contain only the open intervals, or even just the closed intervals, etc. This makes no difference in defining the Borel $\sigma$-field.(*))

Fix some $\mathcal F \in \mathcal A$. Your first question asks,

> How can we say that $\mathcal F$ contains all the intervals?

I'm not sure this question is very meaningful because the answer is just that we can say that $\mathcal F$ contains all the intervals because that's how we've defined $\mathcal F$.

To illustrate why I think the question isn't very meaningful, consider the following exercise. Let $E$ be the set of all real numbers greater than $7$. You could just as well ask how can we say that $E$ contains all the real numbers greater than $7$. The answer, in this case, is the same. We can say that $E$ contains all the real numbers greater than $7$ because we've defined $E$ to have this property. (**)

For your second question, one example of a $\sigma$-field that contains all the intervals, as I pointed out in a comment is the power set of $\mathbb R$.

(*) This is because if $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-field that contains all the open intervals, then it contains all the other intervals as well, because they can be written as a countable union/intersection of sets already in $\mathcal F$. For example, we have that $$ [0,1] = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(0-\frac 1n , 1 + \frac 1n \right) \in\mathcal F. $$

(**) Of course, you may at this point ask what makes this way of defining sets valid, and that would be an excellent question to ask. This then gets into issues dealt with in the field of set theory, which you can look into if you're interested. However, for most of mathematics outside of set theory, we typically take for granted that we can define sets in this way without worrying too much about how exactly this procedure works.

Comment: I read a theorem just like your note, but I am confused about it. Since the Borel $\sigma$-field contains all intervals is different from Borel $\sigma$-field contains only open intervals. Is the property of $\sigma$-field, countably set operations make the open intervals "become'' other kinds of intervals such that the $\sigma$-field containing only open intervals can also contain all intervals?

Comment: Yes. For example, $$ [0,1] = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(0-\frac 1n, 1 + \frac 1n\right). $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @廖倪徵 You're welcome. If you've found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.